# ROS on Raspberry 3

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Is there anyone already install ROS on raspberry pi 3?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230076/ros-on-raspberry-3/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-24**:
I have not heard any success stories yet. I'd suggest you start with an installation of Ubuntu 14.04 if possible and then follow the UbuntuARM instructions.

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-03-24**:
Ubuntu mate?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-24**:
Most of the Ubuntu MATE images that I see are based on Ubuntu 15.04, which isn't supported by the ARM builds of ROS.

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-03-24**:
so which ubuntu should be install it in my raspberry? i don't found ubuntu for raspberry

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-25**:
I can't find a version of Ubuntu 14.04 that is compatible with the Raspberry Pi 3 either.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-03-25**:
I used an Ubuntu 15,04 image and compiled ROS (core) from sources. I didn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just finished successfully installing ROS Indigo on my raspberry pi 3 with debian jessie. I installed from source using this guide:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

The guide is greatly detailed, but you have to remember to be patient for it will take a lot of time and energy to successfully install ROS from source. And remember to apply the patches for "collada-dom-dev" and "rviz" if you want to install the full-desktop version.

---

Originally posted by [Clapton-Is-God](https://answers.ros.org/users/26765/clapton-is-god/) with karma: 76 on 2016-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on 2016-05-25**:
Hi. Could you please tell me where the patch for collada-dom-dev is? There is a link on the tutorials page but I couldn't find the patch on the link given. And how is it to be installed?
Thanks.

**Comment by [Clapton-Is-God](https://answers.ros.org/users/26765/clapton-is-god/) on 2016-05-26**:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ros-sig-embedded/26XlDtZhyNs/OexZAx6BCBcJ
From there, there is an attached file that you can download.
then go to folder: cd ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot_model/collada_urdf/src
place the file there and rename it to fix.patch
then apply the patch: patch < fix.patch

**Comment by [Clapton-Is-God](https://answers.ros.org/users/26765/clapton-is-god/) on 2016-05-26**:
It is also mentioned in the guide to change the name from "collada-dom" to "collada-dom-dev". That also did not work for me as rosdep still could not find collada-dom-dev. I changed the name from "collada-dom" to "libcollada-dom2.4-dp-dev" and that fixed the issue.

**Comment by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on 2016-05-26**:
Thanks. But for me it seems the folder that you suggested is not/has not been installed. There's no robot_model folder. Do you know why that would be?

**Comment by [Clapton-Is-God](https://answers.ros.org/users/26765/clapton-is-god/) on 2016-05-27**:
are you installing ros command line or ros desktop version?

**Comment by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on 2016-05-27**:
ros command line version

**Comment by [Clapton-Is-God](https://answers.ros.org/users/26765/clapton-is-god/) on 2016-05-27**:
For the ros comm you don't need to build collada, you only need libconsole-bridge-dev and liblz4-dev. You can skip to the next step of the installation: resolving dependencies.

**Comment by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on 2016-05-27**:
Thank you !

**Comment by [Pratik Somaiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/27312/pratik-somaiya/) on 2016-06-28**:
Hello,
I am following the same for desktop version. All worked find but at last while building the catkin workspace I'm getting cmake error for rqt_topic. Can you help me? If you need any more information I can give you.

**Comment by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on 2016-06-29**:
I'm sorry but I don't have my RPi with me so I can't really test out any solution. Moreover I'm not sure of the desktop installation. Hopefully someone else will be able to shed light on this, perhaps if add the error message people might be able to help better.

**Comment by [Pratik Somaiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/27312/pratik-somaiya/) on 2016-06-29**:
Ok. I have asked it as a new question here :[link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/238391/rqt_topic-catkin_make-error-of-rt_library/)

**Comment by [hasnain](https://answers.ros.org/users/33864/hasnain/) on 2018-02-25**:
Hi, I am facing a problem while installing ros indigo on my RPI 3 with the urdfdom-headers installation. I am following the following tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

The error is:
Makefile:180: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' fail

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can do a Chroot 14.04,  on the 15.04 system.
I did this for the dragonboard 410c and it works.

Most likely I will do this for the RPI3 or just compile natively

---

Originally posted by [Shawn Schaerer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23929/shawn-schaerer/) with karma: 106 on 2016-03-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One easy way: Ubuntu Mate Xenial (https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/) with ROS Kinetic  (http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu)
Works fine on my RPI3

---

Originally posted by [Sylvain](https://answers.ros.org/users/26532/sylvain/) with karma: 11 on 2016-05-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2016-08-17**:
This is the best way, worked also fine for me. I had to use the  shadow-fixed repos though (http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository)